# Office 365 SharePoint list notify on new item

Tags: ios, sharepoint, push-notification, office365

I am looking at creating a business app for our company that will simplify specific tasks. These correspond to items in Lists in SharePoint hosted in Office 365.

It is basic enough to use the Office 365 iOS SDK to get list items, but we would like to add push notifications for new items in specific lists (e.g. announcements). My only solution so far is an Azure Mobile Service which polls the list and then can use push notifications from here to notify the device of the update.

Is there a way to notify a remote app/service when a new item is created in the SharePoint List? i.e. maybe a web hook type service that could POST to our web service (maybe azure notification hubs or azure mobile services) on creation or something directly from SharePoint that can send push notifications to a custom iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Office 365 so you need a Remote Event Receiver for when the item is added to the list.  The link below shows how to create one. You can have this event run your code to create the push notification in the Azure Notification Hub.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj220043(v=office.15).aspx

You may also want to take a look at the updated PnP guidance on Remote Event Receivers
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers

Updated:
If you follow the [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/) (thanks @efimovandr) to wire up your iOS application to use the Azure notification hub, your Remote Event Receiver only needs to contain the code in the [Send Notification from BackEnd](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/#send) step, which writes an item to the Service Bus Notifications when the ItemAdded event fires on your list.

Comment: Can this be added to a simple list of site column? i.e. without the need for creating a custom app.

Comment: No, the only event receivers in Office 365 are the remote event receiver, which run in an app.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how all this will work, but this seems the most promising. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not good in SharePoint but looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407274(v=office.14).aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163784(v=office.15).aspx) article I can see that it is possible to write a handler which is called on SharePoint side when new item appears in a list. In that handler you could send a push notification using Azure Notification Hub. Just look at [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/).